# ssh -t and ssh lands in different directory

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I wish to ssh into a remote server and run a series of commands like (just some random commands)

```
touch foo.txt
echo 'bar' > foo.txt
cd ..
ls
```

and stay in that connection.

Someone suggested me using `ssh -t $server "commands; bash"`. It worked but it landed me in a different directory than if I just do `ssh $server`. Any ideas why this happens?

(I'm studying existing code in a repo, so I wonder what is the mechanism that make this happen and why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas why this happens?

Maybe your `commands` include `cd`. You're executing `commands; bash`, so `bash` starts in whatever directory `commands` end.

The obvious solution is to `cd` back just before you invoke `bash`. Try

```
ssh -t $server 'commands; cd "$HOME"; exec bash -l'
```

Notes:

- Single quotes prevent expanding `$HOME` locally; in case you need `commands` to include locally expanded variables, mix the quotes (e.g. `"commands with $var; "'cd "$HOME"; exec bash -l'`).
- `exec`, because you don't need the parent shell on the remote side anymore (or do you?).
- `-l` (equivalent to `--login`) because sole `ssh $server` spawns a login shell and you want your entire command to act alike. Bash as a login shell sources different file(s) than as non-login shell, starting with `/etc/profile`; the rules are somewhat complicated, see `man 1 bash`, look for `INVOCATION`. If one of these files performs `cd` to another directory, you'll get what you get even if `commands` don't change the directory. You didn't tell what the directories ("right" one and "wrong" one) are, so it's hard to even guess what the purpose of this "hidden" `cd` may be.

Or you can run `commands` in a subshell. This won't affect the working directory of the parent shell so `bash` will start wherever the parent shell starts:

```
ssh -t $server '(commands); exec bash -l'
```

You may prefer one solution or the other depending on what `commands` do. For example if `commands` modify the environment of their shell on the remote side then running them in a subshell or not makes a difference for the final `bash`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It's not the `cd` commands that changed the directory. The directory is different when before the `cd`. It seems a script is triggered/executed if I ssh normally but isn't triggered when I use `ssh -t`. Any idea why?

Comment: @KevinHe Does this depend on whether or not Bash is a login shell?

Comment: I'm only able to land in a certain directory if I only do `ssh $server`. If I do anything other than it, e.g. `ssh $server 'pwd'` or `ssh -t $server 'pwd; bash'`, the working directory is different.

Comment: @KevinHe OK, please confirm "anything other than that" includes `ssh -t $server 'pwd; bash -l'`.

Comment: Oh `bash -l` landed me to the same place as I did at `ssh $server`. Can you explain it? Thank you!

Comment: I see so `bash -l` means go to the login shell. I see, so do you know any mechanisms that can customize login shells?

Comment: @KevinHe You "customize" Bash (login shell or not) by editing its [startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). Also see my edited answer, explanation to `-l` is somewhat extended.